# Unicode Character 'BLACK DOWN-POINTING TRIANGLE' in Linux - CSS?

Tags: html, css, linux

I'm trying to use a css file which contains the black down pointing triangle.  In windows it works fine, but as soon as I copy the file to a Linux server the symbol becomes garbage.

How would I use this symbol in a css file on Linux.

```
 content: '.';
```

where the dot should be the symbol.

I've tried:

```
content: &#9660;
content: '&#9660';
```

which is supposed to be the value for the symbol but I'm guessing wrong as it doesnt work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your second attempt is trying to use **HTML** entities in CSS – obviously that doesn’t work. You can use an escaped character instead:

```
content: '\25BC';
```

(It must be in hexadecimal.)

However, you can (and *should*) simply use the character “▼” directly – you just need to save and open your file using the same, agreed on encoding. You fail to do so, and as a consequence the symbol is garbled. The best encoding to use is UTF-8, which is the agreed-on default encoding on the web, on Linux and for many other applications. However, some Windows editors still need to be told to please use this encoding manually.

Comment: ▲ In case you need the complimentary up triangle: `content: "\25B2";` (and be sure to click on the first up triangle for this comment)